# How is UI Evaluated?

Tags: user-interface, software-design, software-distribution

I am new to software engineering and also I like to learn whatever new. I must be very thankful if someone help me to provide further information about `How is a UI evaluated?`.

Any help regarding to this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common, evaluation of User Interface can be based on three common elements

•   Functionality
•   Aesthetics
•   Performance

**Functionality**

1. Is the application usable?
2. Does it enable users to complete tasks?

**Aesthetics**

1. Style
2. How it influencing the users
3. How shown and presented?
4. How colors complement each other?
5. How UI elements convey their meaning?

**Performance**

1. Measured not only by speed, but also reliability.
2. Reliability (Even though an application looks good and feels great, crashes repeatedly, it likely won’t be very successful)
3. Should provide a user with full confidence.